# How to pass default messages from git to editor?

Tags: git

Usually, when I do `git commit` or `git rebase -i`, a `core.editor` is started with default messages.

e.g.)

```
subject line

what happened

[ticket: X]
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD &lt;file&gt;..." to unstage)
#
# modified:   lib/test.rb
#
~
~
".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 14L, 297C
```

In my environment, however, `core.editor` is started **without** any default messages (with blank).

My environment is below.

- Windows 8.1 Pro (64bit)
- Cygwin (mintty 2.1.5, x86_64-pc-cygwin)
- git version 2.5.3

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a default message when you create a git commit? From the [git config doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration), look at the `commit.template` option.

Comment: I set `commit.template`, but no changes. And I want a default messsage not only when commit, but when rebase.

Comment: Then I think you did something wrong because it works for me. I'll make a complete answer so you can follow step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the folder `.git/hooks`?
Default message is defined in their's script.

If there are no script, I guess, your core.editor will show without any default messages.

So, if your `hooks` is blank, use `git init` command on somewhere and then copy their's `hooks`'s script to your blank `hooks` directory.

In addition, I guess this link also would be help you: [GIt - Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

(I want to comment this, but my reputation level does not allow me to do it.)

Comment: `.git/hooks` is not empty. It has `pre-comit.sample`, `pre-rebase.sample` and others.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `commit.template` option of [git config](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration). Follow these steps:

1. Create a file on your system that contains the default text for your commit message. For example, use a command such as the following to create the file: `echo "MY DEFAULT COMMIT MESSAGE IS...." > ~/.mygitmsg.txt`
2. If you want this default message to appear when you make a commit in all repositories on your system, at the command line type `git config --global commit.template ~/.mygitmsg.txt`. Otherwise, if you just want this to work for your current git repository, drop the `--global` switch, executing this command in the git repository for which you want it to be the default message.

If this doesn't work, perhaps there's a problem with your default text editor and git on Windows.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you install Vim via cygwin? See: http://superuser.com/questions/345180/install-vim-in-cygwin